# Can I <embed> only part of an SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I've got an html5 page which is using `<embed>` to load an SVG with a number of top level `<g>`'s. In another part of the page, I'd like to display just one of these `<g>`'s. Is it possible to have embed (or some other technique) load only part of an SVG? (I've got an id tag on the group I need). I can deal with javascript if necessary and have jquery available but I'd rather do it with just HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SVG `<use>` tag to display the data, or

Alternatively you might be able to use an [SVG view](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) to select what area you want e.g.

```
 MyDrawing.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,200,1000,1000))
```

Comment: I ended up using named view's in multiple embed tags and some trial and error to get the view boxes correct. This required some hand editing of the SVG (originally exported from Visio) which I had hoped to avoid but it was minimal and seems to work ok.